# Unable to invoke MenuWillOpen on Swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, macos

I have a swift class as described below. I need to be able to hide a Menu Item when the menu is opened based on a condition.

```
class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate, NSMenuDelegate {

    func menuWillOpen(_ menu: NSMenu) {
        print("Menu opened!")
        // do things
        let mainMenu = NSApplication.shared.mainMenu
        mainMenu?.delegate = self
        let subMenuTag = mainMenu?.item(withTag: 100000)
        subMenuTag?.isHidden = true
    }
```

So my app has a `Main Menu`. It has a subMenu called `File`. Under `File`, I have multiple menu items. I am trying to hide a menu Item which has a tag attached to it, when opened based on some logic.

What could I be doing wrong?

Comment: Is the delegate of the submenu set?

Comment: @vadian I could not find a way to set it

Comment: In Interface Builder ctrl-drag the delegate of the menu to AppDelegate

Comment: Tried to drag and drop the submenu and the menu item from the xib file to the AppDelegate.swift and it did not drag @vadian (Sorry I am new to Swift and XCode)

Comment: It must work. Otherwise drag (without pressing ctrl) from the little plus sign in the delegate line to AppDelegate (the blue cube)

Comment: @vadian I finally got it to work. Thank a lot for your help.